# Cuda - 2D Multiple double sums in each Matrix element

Tags: arrays, cuda, 2d, stride

Same issue as post ([Cuda - Multiple sums in each vector element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644701/cuda-multiple-sums-in-each-vector-element)). How do you perform 2D block striding in both x- and y-direction with varying summation limits. The 2D algorithm can be seen in the CPU and monolithic kernel. I included openmp for the CPU so as to get a more fair speedup result. If there is a way to increase the speed of the CPU function as well I would be happy to find out.

This version of the code takes a 2D array and flattens it to a 1D array. I still use the 2D thread dim3 indexing so I can index the double summations more intuitively.

(p.s. all credit to user Robert Crovella for the 1D striding code.)
The code so far is,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
typedef double df;
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL
#define BSX 1<<5
#define BSY 1<<5
#define N 100
#define M 100

const bool sync = true;
const bool nosync = false;
unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start, bool use_sync = nosync){
  if (use_sync == sync) cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

int divUp(int a, int b) {return (a + b - 1) / b;}

float cpu_sum(int n, int m, df *a, df *b, df *c) {
   df q, r;
   #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
   for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
     q = 0.0f;
     for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        r = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y - j];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y + j] 
                + a[i * n + y + j] * b[(x - i) * n + j];
        }
        q += r;
     }
     for (int i = 1; i < n-x; i++) {
        r = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y - j]
                + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[ i * n + y - j];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y + j] 
                + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[(x + i) * n + j]

                +a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[i * n + y + j] 
                + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[i * n + j];
        }
        q += r;
     }
      c[x * N + y] = 0.25f*q;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

const int P2  = 5;
const int TPB = 1<<P2;
const unsigned row_mask = ~((0xFFFFFFFFU>>P2)<<P2);
__global__ void chebyprod_imp(int n, int m, df *a, df *b, df *c){
   __shared__ df sdata[TPB*TPB];
   int x = blockIdx.x;
   int y = blockIdx.y;
   int row_width_x = (((x)>(n-x))?(x):(n-x))+1;
   int row_width_y = (((y)>(m-y))?(y):(m-y))+1;
   int strides_x = (row_width_x>>P2) + ((row_width_x&row_mask)?1:0);
   int strides_y = (row_width_y>>P2) + ((row_width_y&row_mask)?1:0);
   int i = threadIdx.x;
   df tmp_a;
   df sum = 0.0f;
   for (int s=0; s < strides_x; s++) { // block-stride x loop
      int j = threadIdx.y;  
      for (int u=0; u < strides_y; u++) { // block-stride y loop
         if (i < n && j < m) {tmp_a = a[i * n + j];}
         if (i <= x) {
            if (j <= y) {sum += tmp_a * b[(x - i) * n + y - j];}
            if ((j > 0) && (j < (m-y))) {sum += tmp_a * b[(x - i) * n + y + j] 
                                          + a[i * n + y + j] * b[(x - i) * n + j];}
         }
         if ((i > 0) && (i < (n-x))) {

            if (j <= y) {sum += tmp_a * b[(x + i) * n + y - j]
                          + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[ i * n + y - j];}
            if ((j > 0) && (j < (m-y))) {sum += tmp_a * b[(x + i) * n + y + j] 
                                          + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[(x + i) * n + j]
                                          + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[i * n + y + j] 
                                          + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[i * n + j];}
         }
         j += TPB;     
      } 
      i += TPB;
   }
   sdata[threadIdx.x * TPB + threadIdx.y] = sum;
   for (int s = TPB>>1; s > 0; s>>=1) { // sweep reduction in x
      for (int u = TPB>>1; u > 0; u>>=1) { // sweep reduction in x
      __syncthreads();
         if (threadIdx.x < s && threadIdx.y < u) {
            sdata[threadIdx.x * TPB + threadIdx.y] += sdata[(threadIdx.x + s) * TPB + threadIdx.y + u];
         }
      }
   }
   if (!threadIdx.x && !threadIdx.y) c[x * n + y] = 0.25f*sdata[0];
}

__global__ void chebyprod(int n, int m, df *a, df *b, df *c){
   int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   df q, r;
   if (x < n && y < m) {
      q = 0.0f;
      for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
     r = 0.0f;
     for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y - j];
     }
     for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y + j] 
             + a[i * n + y + j] * b[(x - i) * n + j];
     }
     q += r;
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < n-x; i++) {
     r = 0.0f;
     for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y - j]
             + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[ i * n + y - j];
     }
     for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y + j] 
             + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[(x + i) * n + j]

             +a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[i * n + y + j] 
             + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[i * n + j];
     }
     q += r;
      }
   c[x * N + y] = 0.25f*q;
   }
}

int main(void){
  int size = N*M*sizeof(df);
  df *a, *b, *c, *cc, *ci, *d_a, *d_b, *d_c, *d_ci;
  a  = (df*)malloc(size);
  b  = (df*)malloc(size);
  c  = (df*)malloc(size);
  cc = (df*)malloc(size);
  ci = (df*)malloc(size);

  cudaMalloc(&d_a, size); 
  cudaMalloc(&d_b, size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_ci, size);
  #pragma omp parallel for collapse (2)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    a[i * M + j] = 0.1f;
    b[i * M + j] = 0.2f;
     }
  }

  unsigned long long  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  cpu_sum(N, M, a, b, cc);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D CPU: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  df dtc = dt/(float)USECPSEC;

  std::cout << "Vector cc: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << cc[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";

  cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 dimBlock(BSX, BSY);
  dim3 dimGrid(divUp(N, BSX), divUp(M, BSY)); 

  //std::cout << "dimBlock: " << dimBlock << "\n dimGrid: " << dimGrid << "\n";
  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  chebyprod<<< dimBlock, dimGrid >>>(N, M, d_a, d_b, d_c);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D monolithic kernel: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  printf("Speedup: %fs\n", dtc/(dt/(float)USECPSEC));

  cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "Vector c: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << c[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";

  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  chebyprod_imp<<< dimBlock, dimGrid >>>(N, M, d_a, d_b, d_ci);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D stride kernel: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);

  cudaMemcpy(ci, d_ci, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "Vector ci: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << ci[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";

  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFree(d_b);
  cudaFree(d_c); 
  cudaFree(d_ci);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
  free(cc);
  free(ci);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For me, anyway, the results for the CPU code don't match between the cases where I compile with OpenMP support and without, if I omit `-O3`. I seem to get the correct results with OpenMP compilation if I also specify `-O3`.  I'm not sure why that should matter for correctness, although it obviously has an impact on CPU code performance.
2. You seem to have gotten your grid and block sizing backwards:

   ```
   chebyprod<<< dimBlock, dimGrid >>>(....
   ```

   the first kernel config parameter is the **grid** dimension, not the block dimension.  I'm not sure how this came about since you had it done correctly in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644701/cuda-multiple-sums-in-each-vector-element).
3. As in the previous question, we need to pick a thread strategy and implement it correctly.  You seemed to be confused about striding, so hopefully the code below will clarify things.  The thread strategy I will use here is one **warp** per output point.  A warp is a group of threads with a dimension of 32 (threads) in the x direction, and 1 in the y direction.  Therefore the loop striding will be by an increment of 32 in the x direction, but only 1 in the y direction, to cover the entire space.  The choice of thread strategy also affects grid sizing.
4. You seem to have jumbled the relationships that I think should exist for the two dimensions.  The x direction, `N`, and `n` should all be connected.  Likewise the y direction, `M` and `m` should all be connected (for example, `M` is the dimension in the y direction).
5. When it comes to 2D threadblocks, we want to arrange indexing for coalescing on the GPU such that the index that includes `threadIdx.x` is not multiplied by anything. (A simplified statement of coalescing is that we want adjacent threads in the warp to access adjacent elements in memory.  Since `threadIdx.x` increases by 1 as we go from thread to thread in the warp, we want to use this characteristic to generate adjacent memory indexing.  If we multiply `threadIdx.x` by anything except 1, we break the pattern.)  You have this reversed - where the index including `threadIdx.x` is typically multiplied by the row dimension (`N`, or `n`).  This really cannot be correct, and also does not make for good coalesced access.  To solve this, we want to transpose our indexing and also transpose the data storage for `a` and `b` (and therefore `c`).  In the code below, I have tranposed the indexing for the data setup for `a` and `b`, and also the relevant indexing has been transposed in the striding kernel (only).  In your non-striding kernel and also your CPU version, I have **not transposed** the indexing, I leave that as an exercise for you, if needed.  For the results, numerically, it does not matter, because your entire `a` matrix has the same value at every location, and a similar statement can be made about your `b` matrix.  Numerically, then, for this example code, transposing (or not) has no bearing on the result.  But it matters for performance (of the striding kernel, at least).  **Also note that I believe performing the indexing "transpose" on the "monolithic" kernel should also improve its performance.**  I don't know if it would affect the performance of the CPU version.

I've also added back in the `const` `__restrict__` usage that I included in my previous answer.  According to my testing, on "smaller" GPUs this provides noticeable performance benefit.  It's not strictly necessary for correctness, however.  Here's a worked example with the above changes that gives numerically matching results for all 3 test cases:

```
$ cat t1498.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
typedef double df;
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL
#define BSX 1<<5
#define BSY 1<<5
#define N 100
#define M 100

const bool sync = true;
const bool nosync = false;
unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start, bool use_sync = nosync){
  if (use_sync == sync) cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

int divUp(int a, int b) {return (a + b - 1) / b;}

void cpu_sum(int n, int m, df *a, df *b, df *c) {
   df q, r;
   #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
   for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
       q = 0.0f;
       for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
         r = 0.0f;
         for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y - j];
           }
         for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y + j]
                + a[i * n + y + j] * b[(x - i) * n + j];
           }
         q += r;
         }
       for (int i = 1; i < n-x; i++) {
         r = 0.0f;
         for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y - j]
                + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[ i * n + y - j];
           }
         for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
           r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y + j]
                + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[(x + i) * n + j]

                +a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[i * n + y + j]
                + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[i * n + j];
           }
         q += r;
         }
       c[x * N + y] = 0.25f*q;
       }
     }
}

// choose one warp per output point
const int P2  = 5;  // assumes warp size is 32
const unsigned row_mask = ~((0xFFFFFFFFU>>P2)<<P2);
__global__ void chebyprod_imp(int n, int m, const df * __restrict__ a, const df * __restrict__ b, df * __restrict__ c){
   int x = blockIdx.x;
   int y = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
   int width_x = (((x)>(n-x))?(x):(n-x))+1;
   int height_y = (((y)>(m-y))?(y):(m-y))+1;
   int strides_x = (width_x>>P2) + ((width_x&row_mask)?1:0);
   int strides_y = height_y;
   int i = threadIdx.x;
   df tmp_a;
   df sum = 0.0f;
   if ((x < n) && (y < m)){
   for (int s=0; s < strides_x; s++) { // warp-stride x loop
     for (int j=0; j < strides_y; j++) { // y loop
       if (i < n && j < m) {tmp_a = a[j * n + i];}
       if (i <= x) {
         if (j <= y) {sum += tmp_a * b[(y - j) * n + x - i];}
         if ((j > 0) && (j < (m-y))) {sum += tmp_a * b[(y+j) * n + x - i] + a[(y+j)* n + i] * b[j*n+(x - i)];}
         }
       if ((i > 0) && (i < (n-x))) {

         if (j <= y) {sum += tmp_a * b[(y-j) * n + x+i] + a[j*n + (x + i)] * b[(y - j)*n + i];}
         if ((j > 0) && (j < (m-y)))
           {sum += tmp_a * b[(y+j) * n + x+i]
                +  a[(y+j) * n + x + i] * b[j*n+(x + i)]
                +  a[j*n + (x + i)] * b[(y+j)*n + i]
                +  a[(y+j)*n + x + i] * b[j*n+i];}
         }
      }
      i += 32;
   }
  // warp-shuffle reduction
    for (int offset = warpSize>>1; offset > 0; offset >>= 1)
      sum += __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFFU, sum, offset);
    if (!threadIdx.x) c[y*m+x] = 0.25f*sum;}
}

__global__ void chebyprod(int n, int m, df *a, df *b, df *c){
   int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   df q, r;
   if (x < n && y < m) {
      q = 0.0f;
      for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
     r = 0.0f;
     for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y - j];
     }
     for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x - i) * n + y + j]
             + a[i * n + y + j] * b[(x - i) * n + j];
     }
     q += r;
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < n-x; i++) {
     r = 0.0f;
     for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y - j]
             + a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[ i * n + y - j];
     }
     for (int j = 1; j < m - y; j++) {
        r += a[i * n + j] * b[(x + i) * n + y + j]
             + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[(x + i) * n + j]

             +a[(x + i) * n + j] * b[i * n + y + j]
             + a[(x + i) * n + y + j] * b[i * n + j];
     }
     q += r;
      }
   c[x * N + y] = 0.25f*q;
   }
}

int main(void){
  int size = N*M*sizeof(df);
  df *a, *b, *c, *cc, *ci, *d_a, *d_b, *d_c, *d_ci;
  a  = (df*)malloc(size);
  b  = (df*)malloc(size);
  c  = (df*)malloc(size);
  cc = (df*)malloc(size);
  ci = (df*)malloc(size);

  cudaMalloc(&d_a, size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_b, size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_ci, size);
  #pragma omp parallel for collapse (2)
  for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      a[j * N + i] = 0.1f;
      b[j * N + i] = 0.2f;
      }
    }

  unsigned long long  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  cpu_sum(N, M, a, b, cc);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D CPU: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  df dtc = dt/(float)USECPSEC;

  std::cout << "Vector cc: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << cc[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";

  cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 dimBlock(BSX, BSY);
  dim3 dimGrid(divUp(N, BSX), divUp(M, BSY));

  //std::cout << "dimBlock: " << dimBlock << "\n dimGrid: " << dimGrid << "\n";
  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  chebyprod<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(N, M, d_a, d_b, d_c);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D monolithic kernel: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  printf("Speedup: %fs\n", dtc/(dt/(float)USECPSEC));

  cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "Vector c: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << c[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";

  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  // Perform chebyprod on N elements
  dim3 dimGrid2(N, (M+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y);
  chebyprod_imp<<< dimGrid2, dimBlock >>>(N, M, d_a, d_b, d_ci);
  dt = dtime_usec(dt,sync);
  printf("Time taken 2D stride kernel: %fs\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  printf("Speedup: %fs\n", dtc/(dt/(float)USECPSEC));

  cudaMemcpy(ci, d_ci, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "Vector ci: [ ";
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    std::cout << ci[k] << " ";
  std::cout <<"]\n";
  df max_error = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < N*M; k++)
    max_error = fmax(max_error, fabs(c[k] - ci[k]));
  std::cout << "Max diff = " << max_error << std::endl;

  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFree(d_b);
  cudaFree(d_c);
  cudaFree(d_ci);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
  free(cc);
  free(ci);
}
$ nvcc -O3 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -arch=sm_52 -o t1498 t1498.cu
$ ./t1498
Time taken 2D CPU: 0.034830s
Vector cc: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Time taken 2D monolithic kernel: 0.033687s
Speedup: 1.033930s
Vector c: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Time taken 2D stride kernel: 0.013526s
Speedup: 2.575041s
Vector ci: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Max diff = 8.52651e-13
$
```

CUDA 10.1.105, Fedora 29, GTX 960

Note that when we run this same test on a Tesla V100, which can take the most advantage of the "extra" threads available in the striding kernel case, the benefit is more obvious:

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=32 ./t1498
Time taken 2D CPU: 0.031610s
Vector cc: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Time taken 2D monolithic kernel: 0.018228s
Speedup: 1.734145s
Vector c: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Time taken 2D stride kernel: 0.000731s
Speedup: 43.242137s
Vector ci: [ 198.005 197.01 196.015 195.02 194.025 193.03 192.035 191.04 190.045 189.05 ]
Max diff = 8.52651e-13
```

If you perform the indexing "transpose" on your monolithic kernel similar to what I have done in the striding kernel, I think you'll end up in a performance situation that is roughly similar to where you ended up in the last question.  Little or no performance benefit for the striding kernel over your monolithic kernel on a "small" GPU.  ~5x improvement on a "large" GPU.